# Newly added button doesn't activate onclick function

Tags: jquery, html

So I have two different buttons:

`<input type='button' class='EditData btn btn-warning' value='Edit' name="{{id}}">`

`<input type='button' class='AddNew btn btn-success' value='Add Allocation' id="{{id}}">`

This is my JQuery

```
$(function () {
    $('.AddNew').click(function(){
        console.log(this.name);
    });
    $('.EditData').click(function() {
         var y = document.getElementById("location_"+this.name);
         y.innerHTML = '<input type="button" class="AddNew btn btn-success" value="Add Allocation" id="'+this.name+'">'
    });
});
```

AddNew just prints something to the console.
EditData replaces the EditData button with an AddNew Button.

AddNew works successfully. 
EditData successfully replaces itself with an AddNew button, however this button doesn't not work as intended and doesn't print anything on console when clicked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to use something like this :

```
$("body").on("click", ".AddNew", function(){
   console.log("test");
});
```

Comment: You could also use the jquery delegate method https://api.jquery.com/delegate/

Comment: Awesome, this works for just `console.log("test")`. What if I wanted `console.log(this.name)`?

Comment: @BenjaminJu It should still work, no? Usually in this case `this` would refer to `AddNew`. I might be wrong.

Comment: @LukasGund no, .delegate() was deprecated ages ago in favor of .on()

Comment: @ArmedinKuka No, it doesn't work. $(this) has a bunch of information but $(this).data is undefined and I haven't found a way to access either this.name or this.id

Comment: Don't use `$(this).name`. Just use `this.name` or `this.id`. It works for me.

Comment: Awesome, thanks :)

Comment: My pleasure =))